Trying to configure a dependency for project in eclipse , but changes are not reflected when running the main project
I have a main project in eclipse ,for which i have many dependent libraries added as jars.
I'm working on one of those jar's source code ( the repo its jar-ed from ), and wanted to reflect my changes directly onto the main project.
for this I added the source project as a dependency into the main project using the Java build path -> projects -> classes option.
everything works and compiles well , but the changes i made aren't reflected in the main project.
Anything that I might be doing wrong ?

What is the "Java build path -> projects -> classes option"? Please use exactly the terms displayed in the user interface.

java build path -> projects -> classpath -> add
java build path.-> libraries -> classpath -> add class folder.
these are the options i tried

If you want to use the dependencies of the added project, in the the added project you have export them in Java Build Path, in tab Order and Export by checking the checkboxes. Your problem is unclear to me. Please provide a minimal reproducible example.
